# Why can’t I select an object to change material?

Tags: objects, collections, outliner

I have appended a car into my scene, and when I go into the outliner, my object is a collection (pic 1), and when I select it, all of my options to edit the material and such disappear (pic 2). **Why is this object like this?**
[image]
[image]

Comment: that looks like a linked asset, not an appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"CAR BODY.001" isn't a collection, it's an instance of a collection (the icon for a collection instance is the orange double-box, instead of the single white box). Collection instances cannot be edited, you can only edit the original collection.

[image] - Collection

[image] - Collection instance

The actual collection might be in the same scene or it might be in a different blend file (linked through an asset library or simply appended as an instance). In this case you said you appended the asset, so you probably appended a collection with "Instance Collections" checked.

The checkbox is in the file browser window that opens when you click on Append:

[image]

To edit the objects inside the instance you have to edit the original collection. But beware, changes made in the original collection will affect all instances of that collection, so keep that in mind if you have multiple instances of the same collection.